# Why is the width and height changed after clicking tabs?

Tags: html, css

I have index.html, main.js, main.css, ajax.php files on my site: http://goo.gl/HpLQc

I have `#home-copy` set to `height:auto !important`. When user clicks above link, the main page is displayed. However, if user clicks the logo (foxcode), the width and length changes.

Why does it happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: Is it because the page width changes due to it adding a scrollbar?

Comment: yap , i think so,  do you know how to solve it? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add to the **body**

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This will hide the content that stand out of the box. But adding this to the body is not the 'cleanest' method.

Comment: or keep the scroll bar always visible in case it is usefull : overflow;scroll

Comment: hi Benjamin,  it does not solve my problem. It cause other issue.